# I can't create a "nordvpn" folder in /run

Tags: sudo, directory, ls, runlevel

As you can see on the joined picture.

1 - When I type : sudo mkdir nordvpn in /run
I can create a folder "nordvpn".
I type once "ls"; I can see the folder, I type a second times "ls" and the folder has disapeared.

but

2- When I type : sudo mkdir a in /run
I can create a folder "a".
I type once "ls"; I can see the folder, I type a second times "ls" and the folder is still there.

[screen capure of the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saiPJ.png)

Comment: Why screen capture, when you can copy/paste the command and output???

Comment: *users* are not supposed to create directories in `/run/` - the programs themselves or SystemD are supposed to handle creation.  Why are you trying to create a directory in `/run` which is a non-persistent space?  Also, just copy-paste your commands and output in - screenshots of text are less useful than actual text.

Comment: What no one has asked is why you are trying to do this. Are you trying to get nordvpn to do something like start when the computer starts? If so ask the nordvpn people if this can be done and how. With expressvpn there is a command that does that as an example.

Comment: 2530p:/run$ nordvpn --version
NordVPN Version 3.11.0
andrew@andrew-HP-EliteBook-2530p:/run$ nordvpn c
Whoops! /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock not found

Comment: Thanks for your comments :  My problem is that Nordvpn doesn't lauch since the last update .